# Is the following use of indices correct?

Tags: notation

Is the following use of indices correct? A vector $\langle x_i, x_{i+1},...,x_{i+k}\rangle$ is given. For  every such vector a function is defined through
$$\mu=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^k I_A(x_{i+j})}{k+1}\,,$$
where $I_A$ is the indicator function of some set A. Is it mathematically correct notation? In particular the use of $i+j$ as sub index.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. But as you're doubting, you can also choose to use:
\begin{equation}
\mu = \frac{\sum_{j = i}^{i+k} I_A(x_j)}{k+1}
\end{equation}

Comment: Perfectly correct.

Comment: Thanks. Which is more correct --- to use $x_{i+j}$ or double indexing $x_{i_j}$ and again sum over $j$?

Comment: Double indexing is incorrect, as the elements of the vector are 1-dimensional.

Comment: $x_{i_j}$ can be used, but this if you define $i_j:=i+j$. However... why writing this complex $i_j$ instead of its definition $i+j$? Don't make things complex. Good mathematics is characterized by simplicity.

Comment: I was afraid to use as a sub index sum of two natural numbers --- $i+j$ --- because I have not seen it before...

Comment: Well. The first step is meeting it. The next is getting accustomed and familiar to it, especially by using it and discovering its profits. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above, the notation is correct.

Comment: An upvote to this answer is needed to remove this question from the unanswered list.